# Is it possible to open browser in selected screen via intelij-idea

Tags: intellij-idea, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors. First (left) I'm usually using for development and on the second (right) I have my browser opened by Idea and other tools.

Is it possible to configure in Idea on which screen will be opened browser started from Idea, without using any additional soft required installation?

Idea 2016.1.1, Windows 7 Enterprise, Chrome

Thanks

Comment: That, I suspect, would be a function of your operating system.

Comment: There is no setting for this. Given different browsers would support this differently (if at all), it would be cumbersome for IntelliJ IDEA to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party tools like [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) to force certain apps to always open on the specific displays.